# Python filtering for cloudformation stacks with environment names

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, filter, aws-cloudformation

Updated question:
I need to get cloudformation stacks according to the environment. Below is the code I am using for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto3
import datetime
from datetime import date
import subprocess
import re, itertools

from collections import defaultdict

regions = ['us-west-2']

env_names = ["dev", "test", "stage"]

stack_names_found = defaultdict(list) 

for region in regions:
    session = boto3.session.Session(region_name=region)
    cf_client = session.resource('cloudformation')
    for i in cf_client.stacks.all():
        StackStatus = i.stack_status
        Createdtime = i.creation_time
        StackName1 = i.stack_name

        for env_name in env_names:
            if ('-' + env_name + '-') in StackName1:
                stack_names_found[env_name].append(StackName1)
            output = {'StackName': stack_names_found,
                       'Createdtime': Createdtime, 
                       'Status': StackStatus
                         }
            print(output)
```

StackName in output looks like this:

```
{'StackName':defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'test': ['customer1-test-server1', 'customer2-test-server1', 'customer3-test-server1','customer3-test-server1', 'customer1-test-server2]})
```

Instead of:

```
['customer1-test-server1']
['customer2-test-server1']
['customer3-test-server1']
['customer3-test-server1']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the following version, which uses [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and creates dictionary of stack names for each `env_name`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto3
import csv
import datetime
from datetime import date
import subprocess
import re, itertools

from collections import defaultdict

regions = ['us-west-2']

env_names = ["dev", "test", "stage"]

stack_names_found = defaultdict(list) 

for region in regions:
    session = boto3.session.Session(region_name=region)
    cf_client = session.resource('cloudformation')
    for i in cf_client.stacks.all():
        StackStatus = i.stack_status
        Createdtime = i.creation_time
        StackName1 = i.stack_name
        
        for env_name in env_names:
            if ('-' + env_name + '-') in StackName1:
                stack_names_found[env_name].append(StackName1)
            
print(stack_names_found)
```

Please note that I haven't run the code, thus some adjustment may need to be needed to make it fully work.

Comment: I am having all output as list instead of dictionary when trying to get output as:
            for env_name in env_names:
                if ('-' + env_name + '-') in StackName1:
                    stack_names_found[env_name].append(StackName1)
                    output = {'StackName': stack_name_found, 'Createdtime': Createdtime, 'Status': StackStatus}

StackName in outputlooking like this: 

defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Inf': ['customer1-test-server1', 'customer2-test-server1', 'customer3-test-server1','customer3-test-server1', 'customer1-test-server2]})

Comment: @snr You can updated the question with the output. Its difficult to read the code without any formatting.